# How to explode an object using Amazon Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have a table, **myTable**, with a column, **meta_data**, where each row has an object with this structure: `{prop_1: 'some_value', prop_2: 17 }`.

How do I transform this table so that it will look like:

| prop_1 | prop_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 'some_value' | 17 |
| ... | ... |

I tried this:

```
SELECT meta_data.*
FROM myTable
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(meta_data) AS meta_data
```

But it resulted in INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Cannot unnest type: row(prop_1 varchar, prop_2 integer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select appropriate fields from row:

```sql
SELECT meta_data.prop_1, meta_data.prop_2
FROM myTable
```

or try creating table alias and expanding via it (works in latest Trino version at least):

```sql
SELECT t.meta_data.*
FROM myTable t
```